# Layer-hosted NSView with lots of CALayers inside (WindowServer - CPU 100%)

Tags: performance, cocoa, calayer, cpu-usage, nsview

**I have an interesting case for you.** And need help.

My Mac app has a layer-hosted NSView with lots of layers and sublayers and sub-sub layers inside. Imagine a Finder window with items (icons, text labels)... something like that. Each item has a button, selection background layer.

And everything is fine until you have 1000 of those items.

Now with lots of those items, my app becomes unresponsive when I try to interact with this view. And the tricky part is that it is not my app that consumes the CPU, but WindowServer. It gets to 100% and the system freezes for some time.

**Important Note:**

My view is a part of the app interface. There is a main window with other views. They have their own structure as well.

And I've noticed that if I put this layer-hosted view into a separate window, it works just fine with no freezes having the same 1000 items. But starts to halt the system if I put it back to the main window.

**The Question**

1. What is it in my app (views/layers) that makes WindowServer go mad?
2. Why does placing this view to a separate window helps?

I've run some tests and removed all the sublayers for every item, leaving just one-two for each. It has reduced the load on the system, but still bad. I've disabled all the drawings - just small images for the icons. Didn't help as well.

Comment: Give us the related code.

Comment: Well, the view is pretty complicated. So it is a lot of code from different places. Don't see how can I post it here in a simple way.

Answer (score 3):

`WindowServer`'s main job is drawing graphics related things for macOS which means everything you can see from the entire screen, you must go through `WindowServer` and let it draw for you.

There are many reasons why WindowServer is using high CPU.

1. You have complicated drawing methods in your application. -- Try to simplify your drawing method.
2. You have a lot of graphics on the desktop so that WindowServer not only draw your application but also desktop graphics. -- Try to clean your desktop.
3. You have some applications opened which require complicated graphics drawing? -- Try to close that application.

Until seeing your exact code, I cannot tell you why placing elements into separate window can help. Perhaps the window itself hide something to make it easier to draw?

One of my software has a lot of graphic elements and with animations. But I never have encountered your issue. How about creating a testing project and try the similar things? Sometimes, it could help to see the problem on the clearer project structure.

I created a simple demo which has 100*100 sublayers in the window. It seems no problems at all.

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    self.window.contentView?.wantsLayer = true

    let size = 10
    for i in 0..<10000 {
        let x = i%100
        let y = i/100

        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.frame = NSRect(x: x*size, y: y*size, width: size, height: size)
        layer.backgroundColor = .random()
        self.window.contentView?.layer?.addSublayer(layer)
    }

}



   func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}

extension CGFloat {
    static func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    }
}

extension CGColor {
    static func random() -> CGColor {
        return CGColor(red:   .random(),
                       green: .random(),
                       blue:  .random(),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Good point about the test project. Will try and be back with results. Thank you!

Comment: #2 and #3 are not applicable, because WindowServer has no issues without my app being launched (having a lot of items inside).

Comment: #1 is good, but still I don't see any complicated drawings. It is mostly icons + text. Icons are drawn via layer contents, text is drawn using the layer's delegate and drawLayer:inContext: I've tried to disable (and remove) all the ather layers, leaving just icons. And still it is a problem with CPU and WindowServer, still freezing and lagging.

Comment: @UJey Can you try test application and just icons without using your code? Do you still see the problem?

Comment: will do that tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! I've just got back to this issue and discovered when with lots of items my layer-hosted view consumes 25-30% CPU for WindowServer process just by placing mouse above it. I mean, I've hovered my "complicated" view with the mouse and left the mouse still. The result is 25-30% CPU for WindowServer process. Nothing was happening. Just mouse over my view.

Comment: I've checked the code, there should be no tasks running, no re-drawing, no mouse tracking. But still something makes the WindowServer work hard. How can I find the cause of this?

Comment: I've compiled a sample project, trying to reproduce the same setup (simplified of course). It works fine even with 5000 of identical items. Stuck on trying to find the "overload" reason in my working project. Need help.

Comment: @UJey you can split the whole project into small pieces. Every time add one more layer of code and have a test until you can find the issue.

Comment: @UJey Or is it possible setup a new project? And copy and paste your existing code and have a test.

Comment: I copied a big part of the project into new test project (all the pieces that was connected to my view), but it works fine there :( And I cannot profile the WindowServer just like I can do my own project... Now I am stuck trying to find out the hidden cause of WindowServer load when idle and the difference between work and test projects setups.

Comment: @UJey To me, if the test project works, then it is good! Because you can restart new project which doesn't have any issue. It won't take long time so it is better move on new project instead of stucking there?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out that if the window is borderless, you will have troubles. But making the styleMask `NSWindowStyleMaskTitled` completely resolves the issue.

It seems that borderless windows are handled differently.

Now I need to find the way to hide all the titlebar controls, keeping the mask. I've already done this:

- added `NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask` to the window mask
- added

  ```
  self.titlebarAppearsTransparent = YES;
  self.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden;
  ```

But the window still shows the 3 buttons at the left top.

**Any ideas how to hide them?**

Comment: Extra info: the window should also have `NSWindowStyleMaskResizable` to remove WindowServer overload.

Comment: Ok. Looks like `[[self standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton] removeFromSuperview];` is a working approach.